# phplint undeclared function

Tags: php, sublime-text-plugin, phplint

I'm using **phplint** to check my PHP code. I'm om Windows 8.1 and my editor is Sublime Text 3.
Here is a little code snippet of mine:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$singleHeight = 129;
$singleWidth = 97;
$bild = imagecreatetruecolor(1170, 520);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($bild, 248, 154, 38);
imagefill($bild, 0, 0, $orange);

....

?>
```

And here's the phplint report:

1: function 'header()' (still) not declared. Guessing signature from its usage. Hint: it's better to declare the functions before their usage
    1: undeclared function 'header()' used only once: misspelled?
    3: variable '$singleHeight' assigned but never used
    4: variable '$singleWidth' assigned but never used
    5: function 'imagecreatetruecolor()' (still) not declared. Guessing signature from its usage. Hint: it's better to declare the functions before their usage
    5: undeclared function 'imagecreatetruecolor()' used only once: misspelled?
    6: function 'imagecolorallocate()' (still) not declared. Guessing signature from its usage. Hint: it's better to declare the functions before their usage
    6: undeclared function 'imagecolorallocate()' used only once: misspelled?
    7: function 'imagefill()' (still) not declared. Guessing signature from its usage. Hint: it's better to declare the functions before their usage
    7: undeclared function 'imagefill()' used only once: misspelled?

What is that thing with the undeclared functions? The code itself works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using this PHPLint http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html ?

By default it seems to not load any of the standard libraries, so when you check the code the linter is starting from scratch, nothing has been declared.

When you run the code on your server things like GD and standard PHP functions like header are enabled so it will work fine.

You can get around this by adding these libraries to the top of your code like so

```
<?php /*. require_module 'gd'; .*/ ?>
<?php /*. require_module 'standard'; .*/ ?>
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$singleHeight = 129;
$singleWidth = 97;
$bild = imagecreatetruecolor(1170, 520);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($bild, 248, 154, 38);
imagefill($bild, 0, 0, $orange);
```

This will output like so

```
BEGIN parsing of test-32AOqf
1:      <?php /*. require_module 'gd'; .*/ ?>
2:      <?php /*. require_module 'standard'; .*/ ?>
3:      <?php
4:      header("Content-type: image/png");
5:      
6:      $singleHeight = 129;
7:      $singleWidth = 97;
8:      $bild = imagecreatetruecolor(1170, 520);
9:      $orange = imagecolorallocate($bild, 248, 154, 38);
10:     imagefill($bild, 0, 0, $orange);
END parsing of test-32AOqf
==== test-32AOqf:7: notice: variable `$singleWidth' assigned but never used
==== test-32AOqf:6: notice: variable `$singleHeight' assigned but never used
==== ?: notice: unused package `stdlib/dummy.php'
==== ?: notice: unused module `mysql'
==== ?: notice: unused module `pcre'
==== ?: notice: required module `standard'
==== ?: notice: required module `gd'
Overall test results: 0 errors, 0 warnings.
```